# how can i send json to server?

Tags: jquery, json

```
$("#txt").click(function(){
var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + inputs.length);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
          '<input type="text" name="textbox' + i + 
          '" id="textbox' + inputs.length + '" value="" >' + '<input type="button" id="button'+inputs.length +'"value="x">');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#holder");

 inputs.push(['text','textbox'+i,'textboxtx'+i]);

    i++;
var jsonString = JSON.stringify (inputs);

     });
```

**send json array to server**
how can i send inputs[] to local server wamp to be read by a controller written in symfony

```
<input type="button" id="txt" value="Add TextBox" style="" /><br>
```

Comment: Since using jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: As you don't want to use ajax, why don't you use simply a form ?

Comment: but this is a user interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `$.ajax` example

```
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: 'POST',
   contentType:'application/json',
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   dataType:'json'
});
```

The key part is `contentType: 'application/json'` to make sure the server receive as json and not other type

Comment: is there another way without using ajax?